# Fail to import matplotlib in Julia with @pyimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, julia

Hello I'm trying to use matplotlib in Julia with command `Pkg.build("PyCall")` `using PyCall` `@pyimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt` but I keep getting the following error message:

```
PyError (ccall(@pysym(:PyImport_ImportModule), PyPtr, (Cstring,), name)) <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>
RuntimeError("Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other backends. If you are using (Ana)Conda please install python.app and replace the use of 'python' with 'pythonw'. See 'Working with Matplotlib on OSX' in the Matplotlib FAQ for more information.",)
  File "/Users/mymac/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/Users/mymac/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/Users/mymac/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _macosx
```

Here are the following steps that I already tried

- In a Julia kernel tried to run `@pyimport math` ==> this works
- In a Python kernel, I tried to run `import matplotlib as plt` ==> it works
- I uninstall all the python versions on my MacOS 10.13.2 and reinstall Python version 3.6.5. I still get the same error message.
- In Terminal i tried to run: `$ curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` and then `python3 get-pip.py` but still getting the error message in Julia
- After removing Python from `/Users/mymac/Library/`, It seems that Julia recreates  the path `/Users/mymac/Library/Python/2.7/`

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: For those who downvoted my question, I would be glad to have the reason why the question was downvoted: If 1. the style of the question or the accuracy of the question is not good enough, just write it : I'm very eager to learn and improve how to write better questions. If it’s 2. because the question is a duplicate, just write as an answer: I would more than glad to upvote it and accept it as an answer. If 3. there is another reason that I didn’t get please write it as well. But I must say that I find the attitude of just downvoting “for free” without any explanation irritating and useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing the PyPlot.jl package in Julia?

```
Pkg.install("PyPlot")
```

Comment: Many thanks @juliohm! After running `Pkg.add("PyPlot")` and `using PyPlot`, I can now run `plot()` which is, if I understand correctly a copy of matplotlib in Julia. The only small detail is that, when I tried to import pyplot from python with the command `@pyimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, the error message `@pyimport: plt already defined` is given. Apparently there is already a function `plt()` in Julia. Alternatively I can run `@pyimport matplotlib.pyplot as mplt`. Thanks again

Comment: The PyPlot.jl package exports every matplotlib function that you need. If any function from matplotlib is missing, please open an issue on GitHub and the maintainers will fix it. Another suggestion is to check the Plots.jl package. It works with many other backends, not just matplotlib from Python.